# How to update multiple rows in one column all at once?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im trying to do a procedure to update an (for now) empty column recently added.

In this new column, i will put the values of the result obtained by a join query.
To explain it better, i have this

```
delimiter // 
create procedure update_amount_products (in id int)
begin
update categories set products_amount= 
           (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT( products_to_categories.products_id ) 
FROM categories_description
INNER JOIN products_to_categories ON products_to_categories.categories_id = categories_description.categories_id
INNER JOIN products_description ON products_description.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id
WHERE categories_description.categories_id =id)
WHERE categories_id = id;
end
//
call update_amount_products(id);
```

So what i want, is to not calling the procedure everytime with diferents "ids", i want to update all at once (because there are over 1500 rows with diferents ids). What can i do?

I have been thinking of some kind of "for" to get all the ids and saving them on a variable so later used on my update procedure, but i've seen that there isn't any array possibilty in sql nor foreach.

**EDIT:**
I would like to know if this is somehow possible (altho it doesn't work now)

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE total_updated()

   BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 1 ;
      DECLARE category_length int;

      select count(categories_id) into category_length from categories_description;

      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;

         call update_amount_products(a);

         IF a >= category_length THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$
```

I can't create this last procedure due some stupid warning about delimiter (sometimes happens even when i put the same code that worked before)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 19

Any help is highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it, after several tries i manage to get what i needed, so i'll share my answer.

First i made one procedure to update one single row in the column:

```
delimiter //
create procedure update_amount_products (in id int)
begin
update categories set products_amount= 
           (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT( products_to_categories.products_id ) 
FROM categories_description
INNER JOIN products_to_categories ON products_to_categories.categories_id = categories_description.categories_id
INNER JOIN products_description ON products_description.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id
WHERE categories_description.categories_id =id)
WHERE categories_id = id;
end
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then i realized i could handle the whole column by calling the procedure with another procedure with a loop on it

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_products_amount()

   BEGIN
      DECLARE a INT Default 1 ;
      DECLARE category_length int;

      select max(categories_id) into category_length from categories_description;

      simple_loop: LOOP
         SET a=a+1;

         call update_amount_products(a);

         IF a >= category_length THEN
            LEAVE simple_loop;
         END IF;
   END LOOP simple_loop;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

commit;
```

Finally, all i have to do now, is to call my last procedure and voilá, all my column will be automatically updated.

```
call update_products_amount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the `update` statement, you can refer to a field of the actual record being updated. So in your case, you can refer to the `categories_id` in the subselect, and you don't need to specify it as an external parameter. Maybe you can consider a simple update like this:

```
UPDATE categories c
SET products_amount =
   (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT( products_to_categories.products_id ) 
    FROM categories_description
    INNER JOIN products_to_categories
       ON products_to_categories.categories_id = categories_description.categories_id
   INNER JOIN products_description
       ON products_description.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id
   WHERE categories_description.categories_id = c.categories_id);
```

Moreover, the join with `products_description` seems to be unnecessary, but it is hard to say it for sure without a schema.

Comment: Yes, i noticed after some research that i could do what you explaining here, but when i tried on real, it sent me an error with 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)' message. After all i managed to get what i need (update all the column by using 2 procedures and i show in my answer above). Still thanks for the answer.
Ps: the products_description i use to join for get the name (didn't put on the post, sorry)

Comment: If you got that error message, you tried sg completely different. You can see why mysql reports you such an error [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html). Also, if you just want to count the product_ids, you don't need the name from the product description, so you don't need to join that table.

Comment: The joins i need them for internal purposes, so i leave it like that. About the error message i didn't care that much since it wasn't really helping me to improve (at least in that moment). So as for now, i got everything going fine. Thanks for your concern.